# jquery.cookie and internet explorer cookie issue

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am building an asp.net website using jquery cookie. I have the jquery image slider on that page. In order to retain the scroll position of the slider, I store them in the jquery cookie (I use the jquery.cookie plugin by carhartl). 
for example I use the function as below to create the cookie and write the scroll position in it

```
afterEnd:function(e){$.cookie('scrollposition', e.first().index(), {Path: "/", expires: 0});}
```

this is how read from the cookie

```
start:  parseInt($.cookie('scrollposition'),10) || 0,
```

The above steps works perfectly on firefox. chrome and Opera. But it is not working on Internet Explorer and Safari. **While investigating this issue I found out that changing the cookie management settings on IE and Safari  helps. For example on IE, Tools->Internet options->privacy->Click Advanced-> Enable Override automatic cookie handling and safari->preference->privacy->Block cookies->never.**

Is there any alternative to the cookie? Because most of the people use IE, this cookie approach doesnt seem to help me. Many Thanks in advance

---

for example, my site say www.y.com points to a folder on www.x.com/folder-x. so when you access the site www.y.com through the url www.x.com/folder-x jquery cookie works perfectly. but if you access it from www.y.com, jquery cookie's doesn't seem to work as folder-x is created as a virtual directory on www.x.com. it would be better to use sessions in that case. hope this helps some one.

Comment: guys to add up to the above issue, the website is running inside a virtual folder on IIS server. So this is rendered like an iframe content. I believe that could be the reason why the cookies are not working.